# Fill in a cell of grid with a picture using Tkinter Python

Tags: python, image, tkinter, grid, python-chess

I am creating a chessboard to display my NQueensProblem search. I have made a grid and filled in the cells with colors. However, I can't fill the positions of queens with 'queen picture'. For example, I have a queen at (0, 1) and I want this cell display a queen picture. Please help me with this.
Thank all of you very much!!!
[image]

```
    import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.tix import IMAGETEXT
from matplotlib import colors
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class GUI(tk.Frame) :
    def __init__(self, position, no_of_queens) :
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)
        self.grid()
        self.master.title('Order Queens')

        self.main_grid = tk.Frame(self, bg = '#a39489', bd = 0, width = 50, height = 50)

        self.main_grid.grid(pady = (0, 0))

        self.display_GUI(position, no_of_queens)
        self.mainloop()

    def make_GUI(self, no_of_queens) :
        # make grid
        self.cells = []
        for i in range(no_of_queens) :
            row = []
            for j in range(no_of_queens) :
                if i % 2 == 0 :
                    if j % 2 == 0 :
                        cell_color = '#f2dbbb'
                    else :
                        cell_color = '#832c33'
                else :
                    if j % 2 == 0 :
                        cell_color = '#832c33'
                    else :
                        cell_color = '#f2dbbb'

                cell_frame = tk.Frame(self.main_grid, bg = cell_color, width = 45, height = 45)
                cell_frame.grid(row = i, column = j, padx = 0, pady = 0)
                cell_number = tk.Label(self.main_grid, bg = cell_color)
                cell_number.grid(row = i, column = j)
                cell_data = {'frame': cell_frame, 'number': cell_number}
                row.append(cell_data)

            self.cells.append(row)
        
    def display_GUI(self, position, no_of_queens) :
        self.make_GUI(no_of_queens)

        img = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\queen.gif')
        for i in range(no_of_queens) :
            #label.grid
            self.cells[i][position[i]]['number'].configure(image = img)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    no_of_queens = 8
    position = (1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 7, 4, 6)
    GUI(position, no_of_queens)
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @SriramSrinivasan Sorry. I have updated it

Comment: you may have common problem with bug in `PhotoImage` which removes image when it is not assigned to global variable or class variable. See `Note` at the end of page [PhotoImage](https://web.archive.org/web/20200313162612/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm). You assign `PhotoImage` to local variable `img`. Keep all images on class list - `self.all_img = []` in `__init__` and later in loop `self.all_img.append(img)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is common problem with `bug` in `PhotoImage` which removes image when it is assigned to local variable in function. You have to use global variable or class variable.

See `Note` at the end of page [PhotoImage](https://web.archive.org/web/20200313162612/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm).

(it is link to backup on `archive.org` because original page doesn't exist any more)

---

Use `self.`

```
self.img = tk.PhotoImage(file='test/face.png')
```

and

```
    .configure(image=self.img)
```

[image]